# PHP Regular Expression To check Upper Case and Digits Only

Tags: php, preg-match

I wrote the `PHP` code  using `Regular Expression` to check the string  contains  the combination of `UPPER CASE` and `DIGITS` only. I am not able to test the $str.

```
$str = "ABCD1234";
if(preg_match('[A-Z0-9]', $str)){
    echo "yes";
 }else{
   echo "No";
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
if(preg_match('/^[A-Z0-9]+$/', $str)){
```

`/` and `/` indicate start and end of the regex. `+` indicates that the given set can appear more than just once. `^` and `$` tell the regex that this has to apply for the whole string, not just some part of it

Comment: Nice answer.  You deserve my upVote.

Comment: This will also accept strings that are _only_ uppercase characters or _only_ numbers.

Answer (score 3):

You need to mark the beginning and end of the regex string with /

```
$str = "ABCD1234";

if(preg_match('/[A-Z0-9]/', $str)){
    echo "yes";
 }else{
   echo "No";
}
```

Comment: This matches `qwertA.:?`. You need to add quantifier and anchors.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for the *combination* of uppercase and number strings, meaning you need both types of characters to be in the string, you'll need lookaheads:

```
^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])[A-Z0-9]*$
```

Otherwise a string containing *only* uppercase letters or *only* numbers will also be accepted.

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/DN5HP#v7.4.30)